# Problem with a function of a class of an external file: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, tkinter

I have a window that prints the news content in a textbox. You must first click on the "View Titles" button, then select the title, and finally click on the "View Content" button. It works correctly, without any problems.

In this question, I have placed the window code in a class of an external file `(page1.py)`. The file will be opened in the main file `(main.py)`. If I click on the "View Titles" button it works fine, but if I click on the "View Content" button I get an error in the function `def content`:

```
    item = df.iloc[selection[-1]]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

I would like that when I click on the "View content" button, the content of the news is printed in the textobox. As I said above, the code when it was in a simple file with only one window ... it worked perfectly, while now if put in an external class I have problems.

I am new to Python. Can you show me the code in the answer? Otherwise I may not understand, thanks and sorry

**Main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk
from page1 import Page1

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('480x320')

topbar = tk.Frame(root, bg='#e10a0a', height=43)
topbar.pack(fill='x')

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default') # select a theme that allows configuration of ttk.Notebook
# put the tabs at the left with white background
style.configure('TNotebook', tabposition='wn', background='white', tabmargins=0)
# configure tab with white background initially, yellow background when selected
style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', background='white', width=10, focuscolor='yellow', borderwidth=0)
style.map('TNotebook.Tab', background=[('selected', 'yellow')])

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

page1 = Page1(nb)

nb.add(page1, text='aaaaa', compound='left')

root.mainloop()
```

**page1.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import ttk

import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText 
import requests
import requests_cache 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import json
from dateutil import parser
import datetime
import locale



class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)



        def get_data_for(place):
            headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
            }

            results = []

            response = requests.get(f'https://www.tuttomercatoweb.com/{place}/', headers=headers)
            print('url:', response.url)
            print('status:', response.status_code)
            #print('html:', response.text[:1000])

            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

            #Cover
            cover_news = soup.find('div', {'class':'box pp'})
            link = cover_news.find('a', href=True)['href']
            coverNewsResponse = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
            coverSoup = BeautifulSoup(coverNewsResponse.content, 'html.parser')
            jsonStr = str(coverSoup.find('script'))
            jsonStr = re.search('({.*})', jsonStr).group(1)
            jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
            
            timePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%H:%M")
            datePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            title = jsonData['headline']
            news = f" {timePublished} {place.upper()}, {title} (TMW)"
            results.append( [datePublished, timePublished, place, title, news, link] )

            # Side panel
            side_news = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'box small'})
            for each in side_news:
                link = each.find('a', href=True)['href']
                sideNewsResponse = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
                sideSoup = BeautifulSoup(sideNewsResponse.content, 'html.parser')
                jsonStr = str(sideSoup.find('script'))
                jsonStr = re.search('({.*})', jsonStr).group(1)
                jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
                
                timePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%H:%M")
                datePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                title = jsonData['headline']
                news = f" {timePublished} {place.upper()}, {title} (TMW)"
                results.append( [datePublished, timePublished, place, title, news, link] )
                
                

            news = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "tcc-list-news"})

            for each in news:
                for div in each.find_all("div"):
                    timePublished  = div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'hh serif'}).text
                    datePublished = div.find_previous('div', {'class':'tcc-border upper date'})
                    
                    if datePublished:
                        if datePublished.text in ['Ieri']:
                            yesterday = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
                            datePublished = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                        else:
                            locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') #locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'it')
                            currentYear = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y")
                            dateStr = datePublished.text
                            dateStr = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr + ' ' + currentYear, '%A %d %B %Y')
                            datePublished = dateStr.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    else:
                        datePublished = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    
                    title = " ".join(span.text for span in div.select("a > span"))
                    news = f" {timePublished} {place.upper()}, {title} (TMW)"
                    link  = div.find('a')['href']
                    results.append( [datePublished, timePublished, place, title, news, link] )

            return results

        def all_titles():
            global df

            allnews = []  # local variable

            for place in ['atalanta',  'bologna']:
                print('search:', place)
                results = get_data_for(place)
                print('found:', len(results))
                allnews += results
                text_download.insert('end', f"search: {place}\nfound: {len(results)}\n")

            df = pd.DataFrame(allnews, columns=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title', 'news', 'link'])
            df = df.sort_values(by=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title'], ascending=[False, False, True, True])
            df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title'])
            df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

            listbox_title.delete('0', 'end')

            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                listbox_title.insert('end', row['news'])

        def content(event=None):   # `command=` executes without `event`, but `bind` executes with `event` - so it needs default value
            # tuple
            selection = listbox_title.curselection()
            print('selection:', selection)

            if selection:

                item = df.iloc[selection[-1]]
                #print('item:', item)

                url = item['link']
                #print('url:', url)

                headers = {
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
                }

                # keep page in database `SQLite` 
                # https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache
                # https://sqlite.org/index.html
                session = requests_cache.CachedSession('titles')
                response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
                #response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

                content_download = "\n".join(item.get_text() for item in soup.select("div.text.mbottom"))

                text_download.delete('1.0', 'end') # remove previous content)
                text_download.insert('end', content_download)

        # --- main ---

        df = None

       # window = tk.Tk()
       # window.geometry("800x800")

        frame_title = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_title.pack(fill='both', expand=True, pady=5, padx=5)

        listbox_title = tk.Listbox(frame_title, selectbackground="#960000", selectforeground="white", bg="white")
        listbox_title.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

        scrollbar_title = tk.Scrollbar(frame_title)
        scrollbar_title.pack(side='left', fill='y')

        scrollbar_title['command'] = listbox_title.yview
        listbox_title.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_title.set)

        listbox_title.bind('<Double-Button-1>', content)  # it executes `content(event)`

        # ----

        text_download = ScrolledText(self, bg="white")
        text_download.pack(fill='both', expand=True, pady=0, padx=5)

        # ----

        buttons_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        buttons_frame.pack(fill='x')

        button1 = tk.Button(buttons_frame, text="View Titles", command=all_titles)  # don't use `[]` to execute functions
        button1.pack(side='left', pady=5, padx=5)

        button2 = tk.Button(buttons_frame, text="View Content", command=content)   # don't use `[]` to execute functions
        button2.pack(side='left', pady=5, padx=(0,5))
```

Comment: The `content()` function does not have a local variable named `df`, so it uses the global one which you defined with `df = None`.  What were you expecting?

Comment: Try changing `global df` to `nonlocal df` inside `all_titles()`.  However, suggest to use instance variable instead, i.e. change `df` to `self.df`.

Comment: @John Gordon I'm starting out with Python, sorry for my mistakes. Could you show me the code of what you say in an answer please? Thanks

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you for your suggestion. You're kind. I tried to edit as you said, but I still get errors. Maybe some problems with self, I don't know. Could you show me an answer with the code please? Thanks

Comment: Just replace all `df` by `self.df` in `page1.py`, it works for me.  Other than this, did you try changing `global df` to `nonlocal df` inside `all_titles()`?  Using this, you don't need to change `df` to `self.df`.

Comment: @acw1668 If I replace global df with nonlocal df, I get the error: link = cover_news.find ('a', href = True) ['href'] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'. As for self, maybe I added .self (to df) in the wrong df. If you said it works for you, it means you've tried and thank you so much for your kindness. Could you show me the code in an answer please? (both the solution only with nonlocal, and the solution only with self). Of course I will vote and accept. Thanks and sorry

Comment: If you got the exception mentioned in your last comment, it means that you have fixed the original issue.  The exception in your last comment is due to issue when fetching data from the URL.  If you retry the fetching, it may work.

Comment: @acw1668 True, it works correctly now. Why does it sometimes work and sometimes it doesn't? Anyway, may I ask if you can also show me the solution with selfs (without nonlocal df) please? I am more tempted to use the solution with selfs and not with "nonlocal df". Of course I will vote and accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to fix the issue is to change `global df` to `nonlocal df` inside `all_titles()` function.

However, I would suggest to use instance variable instead by changing all `df` to `self.df`:

```py
class Page1:
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        ...
        def all_titles():
            ...
            # changed df to self.df
            self.df = pd.DataFrame(allnews, columns=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title', 'news', 'link'])
            self.df = self.df.sort_values(by=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title'], ascending=[False, False, True, True])
            self.df = self.df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title'])
            self.df = self.df.reset_index(drop=True)

            listbox_title.delete('0', 'end')

            for index, row in self.df.iterrows():
                listbox_title.insert('end', row['news'])

        def content(event=None):
            ...
            if selection:
                item = self.df.iloc[selection[-1]]
                ...
            ...

        self.df = None
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness. I had come close to the solution with self. I had some things wrong out of distraction. A curiosity please: what is the difference between using global and nolocal? i know global, but i don't know nolocal (never used it). Thanks

Comment: Since you define `df = None` inside a function, it is not a global variable.  When you try to access it inside a nested function, you cannot use `global df` as I said it is not a global variable, so you need to use `nonlocal df` to tell python to look up this variable in upper level scope other than the global scope.

Answer (score -2):

I think you've declared `df` to be a global variable in one of the functions nested under your `__init__` method...then later on in your main section, which actually runs in the `__init__`, you set `df` to `None`. You'll want to be much more careful about making variables global and think a bit more about function scope; do those functions you're defining need to be within the scope of `__init__`, or can they have a different scope?

Comment: It doesn't matter to me if the functions I'm defining must be within the scope of __init__ or they may have a different scope. What ideas do you have on how to solve the problem? As I'm just starting out with Python, could you show me the code please? Thanks

Comment: I am new to Python. Can you show me the code in the answer? Otherwise I may not understand, thanks and sorry

Comment: it looks like @acw1668 has given you some very concrete advice on what to do. as i understand it, stackoverflow generally doesn’t rewrite people’s code for them; it’s a lot more educational to figure it out on your own and make some mistakes along the way. if you have specific questions i’m happy to help!

Comment: On StackOverflow you don't write code on demand, true, but you can write code if a user asks about a certain problem and also shows the error of that particular problem (like I did). ACW1668 is great, it gave me good advice, but I couldn't solve it. Generally speaking (not referring to my question), if a user asks kindly and respectfully for the code in an answer for solving my question and my error generated, he will do nothing wrong. :) Then if a user does not want to answer because he does not have the time or desire, then it is another matter